# Find the sum of all roots $(0, 2\pi)$ such that $\cos(2012x)=\cos(2001x)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

This question is from Math Day at the Beach(mathematical problem solving festival for Southern California high school students).  I am very confused on one of the steps in the solution.

First it goes from
$ \quad \displaystyle \cos(2012x)=\cos(2001x)$

to $ \qquad \qquad \qquad  \dfrac{(e^{i2012x}+e^{-i2012x})}{2}=\dfrac{(e^{i2001x}+e^{-i2001x})}{2}$

which makes sense by De Moivre's thereom. However I don't get how it goes from $$\frac{(e^{i2012x}+e^{-i2012x})}{2}=\frac{(e^{i2001x}+e^{-i2001x})}{2} \\ \implies e^{i4024x}+1=e^{i4013x}+e^{i11x}$$

Can someone break down that step into smaller steps because I am very confused.

Comment: Multiply by $2e^{2012x}$.

Comment: If the usage of complex number is not mandatory use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: @AnginaSeng makes so much sense now thanks

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Are you saying an alternative way is to subtract cos and do sum to product? Does that work? I tried that but I'm not getting the correct answer. I might need an explanation or something

Comment: After following the above comment, you'll get $$\sin\left(\frac{11x}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{4013x}2\right)=0$$ which is much simpler